# なんくるないさ or なんとかなるさ

Tags: meaning

Hello I'm planning to get a tattoo soon and I'm confused between the 2 words do they mean the same thing just written differently? or which is more of broadly accepted?

なんくるないさ (nankuru nai sa)

or

なんとかなるさ (nantoka naru sa)

Comment: If you need the content of the tattoo explained to you, it seems like it might be best to hold off on it.

Answer (score 2):

なんくるないさ is the equivalent of なんとかなるさ (or なるようになるさ) in [the Okinawan language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawan_language). Some people consider Okinawan to be a dialect of Japanese, while others consider it to be a separate language. It's one of the most famous Okinawan phrases, known nationwide, and is suitable at least for a T-shirt or souvenir mug. But if you're not particularly interested in Okinawa, you have no reason to choose it.